# Finding $\lim_{x\to4}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+2x}-3}{\sqrt{x}-2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to solve this limit for a time and have no progress. I tried all I could remember. Can you help me?

$$\lim_{x \to 4}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+2x}-3}{\sqrt{x}-2}\right)$$

Comment: Please put dollar signs around your MathJax in the future.

Comment: Hint: Use L Hopital's rule

Comment: The question restricts the use of this method. I forgot to mention this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt{1+2x}-3}{\sqrt x-2}=\frac{1+2x-9}{(\sqrt x-2)(\sqrt{1+2x}+3)}=\frac{2(x-4)}{(\sqrt x-2)(\sqrt{1+2x}+3)}=$$

$$\frac{2(\sqrt x-2)(\sqrt x+2)}{(\sqrt x-2)(\sqrt{1+2x}+3)}=\frac{2(\sqrt x+2)}{\sqrt{1+2x}+3}$$

and now evaluate your limit...

Comment: Thank you! This really helped me! I was not seeing this! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\frac{\sqrt{1+2x}-3}{\sqrt{x}-2}=\frac{2x-8}{x-4}\frac{\sqrt{x}+2}{\sqrt{1+2x}+3}=2\frac{\sqrt{x}+2}{\sqrt{1+2x}+3}\to2\times\frac{4}{6}=\frac43.$$

Answer (score 0):

Use L'Hospital.

$$\lim_{x\to4} \frac{\sqrt{1+2x}-3}{\sqrt{x}-2}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to4} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2x}}\times 2\sqrt{x}$$

$$=\frac{4}{3}$$